# Infer the correct difference between a global and a superglobal variable in PHP

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I know SUPERGLOBAL variables are associative arrays available in any scope throughtout the script and according to the following excerpt from a post (http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?68618-PHP-global-and-superglobal)

Excerpt:
the difference between "global" and "superglobal" is that a global variable is defined at the top level, but is not initially accessible inside a function, whereas a superglobal is automatically available anywhere within the code.

Now the text i am referring to says (about NATIVE PHP SESSIONS):
PHP creates its SID whenever you use the session_start() function, and also by default if you use certain other session-related functions, such as session_register(). The value of SID is kept in a global variable name PHPSESSID.

Now I am not sure as to how PHPSESSID is accessible. Is it simply $phpsessid or $_SESSION['PHPSESSID'].

Please clear this for me.

Comment: Where is the tutorial or text you're referring to that says this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php

Comment: Ok it's not php.net but it's a text from Wrox publications. Here is the link http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-PHP5.productCd-0764557831.html

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is no `$_SESSION['PHPSESSID']` nor `$phpsessid`. Maybe `$phpsessid` exists if `register_globals` are on.

In order to obtain your session id you can either use `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` or `session_id()`. You can check the [documentation](http://br.php.net/session_id).

Comment: Well let me check and I will get back to u for any further query. thanks.